# Optimalization view SQL query

Tags: sql, function, view, refactoring

I would like to ask about some optimization idea. I am calling view from app, it is not possible to change calling to e.g. stored procedure. View include calling of function, which cause performance trouble.

The view has this structure:

```
select tab.Id, funct.b1 
from table1 tab
join 
    (select a1, b1 from dbo.Function1()) funct on funct.a1 = tab.Id
where...
```

Because of view, I am not able to use temporary table instead of function. Also, is not possible to call stored procedure from view (or from function), cannot fire any trigger in which I can use temporary table... so I don't know how to optimize it...

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Any chance your view meets indexed view requirements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Comment: It is not possible, function include another non indexed views, so my view is not able to be iindexed

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.